# How to XOR hex string with space in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 cipher texts represented in hex. I want to xor cipher text#1 with cipher text#2. This part works fine by `xor_strings` function. Then, I want to xor every letter in the returned string from `xor_strings` with spaces character (which has the ASCII code equal to 20 in hexadecimal). But this part is not working with me and when I run the code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hexor.py", line 18, in <module>
    xored_with_space=xor_space(xored,binary_space)
  File "hexor.py", line 5, in xor_space
    return "".join(chr(ord(xored) ^ ord(binary_space)) for x in xored)
  File "hexor.py", line 5, in <genexpr>
    return "".join(chr(ord(xored) ^ ord(binary_space)) for x in xored)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 4 found
```

Here is the code I am running:

```
def xor_strings(xs, ys):
    return "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for x, y in zip(xs, ys))


def xor_space(xored,binary_space):
    return "".join(chr(ord(xored) ^ ord(binary_space)) for x in xored)

a=raw_input("enter first cipher \n")
b=raw_input("enter second cipher \n")
space="20" #hex ASCII value of space

#convert  to binary
binary_a = a.decode("hex")
binary_b = b.decode("hex")
binary_space=space.decode("hex")

xored = xor_strings(binary_a, binary_b).encode("hex")
xored_with_space=xor_space(xored,binary_space)

print xored
print xored_with_space
```

Can you help me fix the problem?

Comment: The real problem is that your `xor_space` function has an error in the return statement.  It should read `"".join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(binary_space))...`.  You have `xored` instead of `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the function that you wrote that does exactly this ...

```
def xor_space(xored,binary_space):
    return xor_strings(xored," "*len(xored))
```

I also suspect you may not fully understand the word binary and its implications

Im not sure what you think `a.decode("hex")` does ... but Im pretty sure its not doing what you think(although its also possible I am wrong about this) ...

Comment: `a.decode("hex")` converts the `a` from string to hex.

Comment: @user2192774: `'ab'.decode('hex')` -> `'\xab'`, the latter being a single character string containing a binary value equal to 171 decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the ordinal value of the space (`0x20`, or decimal `32`), just use that instead of `binary_space`:

```py
def xor_space(xored):
    return "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ 0x20) for x in xored)
```

However, the actual error in your original function is caused by `ord(xored)`; you meant to put `x` there instead of `xored`. Since `xored` turns out to be a length 4 string in this case, `ord` complains about it not being a single character.